# Count of rows in each table in SYSTABLES

Tags: sql, db2

Is there any way one can get the counts of rows in each table in sysibm.systables in DB2.
I would be really thankful if you get time and give me some advice.

Comment: You can easily generate a script of, let's say, `insert into some_temp_table select count(1) from myschema.mytable` commands for every row found in `sysibm.systables` and execute it afterwards. But, out of interest, what is it for? Is this some educational quiz?

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT TBNAME, TYPE, CARDF, STATSTIME FROM SYSIBM.SYSTABLES` should give you the number of rows present the last time statistics were gathered.

Counting all the rows currently present in all the tables extant in a production system may to be too resource consumptive to be practical.  Also, in an active system, the answers you get will be incorrect by the time you see them because rows are being inserted and deleted constantly.

The above query should give -1 for CARDF and '0001-01-01-00.00.00.000000' for STATSTIME if statistics have not been gathered.

You might want to discuss your need for this information with your DB2 DBAs, they may already have something they use for this purpose.

Some shops are reluctant to allow queries of production catalog tables due to contention fears.  Again, discussing with your DB2 DBAs in advance may alleviate such fears.

Comment: SELECT TBNAME, TYPE, CARDF, STATSTIME FROM SYSIBM.SYSTABLES should give you the number of rows present the last time statistics were gathered.                     Should I perform on each table a separate count?

Comment: When you query SYSIBM.SYSTABLES, a single query will already separate the counts by table into separate rows, one row per table.

Comment: Could you please explain bit in detail?

Comment: @Jen Can you explain your business requirement? Why aren't you OK with approximate number of rows for your tables already got by statistics collection? Why do you need to run a generally expensive process of counting the row number for all your tables instead?

Comment: @ Mark Barinstein I was not convinced that cardf gave no of rows but I got it cleared from my mentor. Thanks for help.                                                                                          @cschneid thankyou for taking your time out and explaining it to me.